# How to add another row to a 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add another row to this 2D ArrayList, so I can add another list. How can I do that?

Something like...

```
List<List<String>> text_list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

text_list.get(0).add("another list item");
text_list.addRow();
text_list.get(1).add("another row list item");
```

Comment: well you already know how to add a `String` to a `List<String>`. Hint: It's the exact same process to add a new `List<String>` to a `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Can you give me an example please, I get what you're saying though just wanna make sure I do it right

Comment: `text_list.add(new ArrayList<>());`

Comment: In most cases though, it's not good practice to directly use a nested list. It's better to wrap it into a class that exposes operations that are relevant to the operations the "2D list" supports